# Rails RSPEC controller testing to count # of users on INDEX page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, controller

Working on controller testing and wanted to test that when I go to the index page, I should see the total number of users created and that should equal all the users that were in fact created. Can't get it to work and no errors are coming up, it just freezes and I have to press control c to exit.

```
    describe "GET #index" do 
    it "show a list of all users" do 
        total = User.all.count
        get :index
        expect(response).to eq total 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

rspec controller tests don't render views by default, testing success might be better start

```
describe "GET #index" do 
  it "show a list of all users" do        
    get :index
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

If you really want to check rendering

```
describe "GET #index" do 
  render_views

  it "show a list of all users" do 
    total = User.all.count
    get :index
    expect(response).to contain total.to_s
    # OR
    expect(response.body).to match total.to_s 
  end
end
```

see: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Answer (score 0):

If you want check displaying of some information on page, it will be better to write integrations test using Capybara.
Purpose of controller tests is to check incoming parameters, variables initialized in controller and controller response (rendering views or redirecting...).
About your question - if you have next controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

you can write next controller test:

```
describe UsersController do 
  it "GET #index show a list of all users" do
    User.create(email: 'aaa@gmail.com', name: 'Tim')
    User.create(email: 'bbb@gmail.com', name: 'Tom')
    get :index
    expect(assigns[:users].size).to eq 2
  end
end
```